# Multiple Bootstrap Modal: Activate Selected Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open 4 or 5 bootstrap modals. Due to space limitations some pop-ups are shown on top of the other modals. How can I activate the selected modal pop up on click?

Comment: Please post some code too.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation displaying multiple modals at once is not supported "out-of-the-box" in bootstrap.  See [Overlapping modals not supported](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

There is a 3rd party library for stacking modals [here](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/).